# How can the Daleks hit moving targets at angles over 45 degrees?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

**Minor spoilers.**

In [*Victory of the Daleks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_of_the_Daleks), the Daleks hit three moving aircraft out of the sky at angles clearly exceeding 45 degrees, with no wasted shots. The accuracy isn't what I'm concerned about; the question is how a Dalek can hit a target that's more above him than in front.

Through all the posters, episodes and minifigures, Dalek shells appear to have fixed barrels, incapable of rotating or turning.

Can the Daleks elevate or depress their gunsticks? Did Churchill outfit the Daleks in turrets or anti-aircraft platforms?

Considering Bracewell's advanced technological abilities, I'm inclined to believe the latter.

I'm a new fan to the series and don't have the background to verify my intuition. Have Daleks ever shot at targets on different elevation than their own?

Comment: In the new series, the Daleks have been able to elevate their gunsticks to a noticeable angle. I don't know if it was a 45 degree angle, but it was certainly there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two considerations:

1. **Their gunsticks can tilt.**

   Their gunsticks certainly have some degree of motion within their socket. For example, here's a scene from s01e06 *Dalek*, the first Dalek episode of the rebooted show, in which a damaged Dalek elevates its gunstick by several degrees:

   [image]

   If you look at this closeup of a Dalek midriff from the same episode, you can get an idea of the range of motion available to the unstuck:

   [image]

   I believe it can move to the point where the silver circle under the gunstick touches the edge of the socket, but no further. But I don’t think that would get up to a 45 degree angle, so we need something more.
2. **The whole Dalek can tilt.**

   In the scene in *Evolution of the Daleks*, we don't actually see the Dalek while it’s firing; it's hidden behind a wall of sandbags. That means it’s quite possible (either by hovering off the ground, or just being parked on a  ramp) for the whole Dalek to be tilted upward, increasing its vertical range. I lean towards the ramp theory over floating, because Churchill never mentions the marvellous flying technology that the Daleks seem to use.

As for the fact that the targets are moving: that probably makes no difference. The Daleks are (supposed to be) some of the most formidable war machines in the universe. They will have encountered moving targets before, and those targets were probably a lot faster and more agile than WWII aircraft.